# Insert component with javascript

Tags: ember.js

have bootstrap alert messages as an ember component (they display success error warning messages...). How could I insert a message on an event? Lets say form validation is not successful, I want to pass a message with the folowing component:

```
{{alert-mes message="The passwords must match" type="error"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embner has two way binding, so you don't need to pass a different message everytime, instead you can have an attribute that changes in the controller, and have your component listen to changes:

```
// controller.js

showModal: false,
message: null,
actions: {
  somethingHapened: function() {
    this.set('message', 'The passwords must match');
    this.set('showModal', true);
  }
}

// template
{{alert-mes message=message type="error" show=showModal}}

// component

onShowModal: function() {
  if (this.get('show')) {
    // display the modal somehow
    // this.$().show(this.get('message'));
  } else {
    // hide the modal
  }
}.observes('show')
```

Comment: I know about that, the code was just an example, I was wondering if it would be possible to simply append the moustache with something like this: $('#someDiv').html('{{block-mes}}');

But you helped me enough, I can work with what you gave me, thanks